# Equal Field in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to Search Two Table in Same City With Mobile Number

```
SELECT top 1 CandidateSerials.MobileNo 
FROM CandidateSerials 
Inner Join EmployerSerials ON CandidateSerials.Id = EmployerSerials.Id  
Where  CandidateSerials.City  <> EmployerSerials.City and EmployerSerials.MobileNo ='000000000'
```

Comment: Question is not clear, please modify.

Comment: I've no idea what your data looks like, what the above query produces, what you *want* it to produce, or anything else. Could you maybe add some information about these things? (At the same time, it'd be worth adding a tag for your specific database system, since a lot of SQL queries end up having to use specific dialect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 CandidateSerials.MobileNo     
FROM CandidateSerials 
INNER JOIN EmployerSerials
ON CandidateSerials.Id = EmployerSerials.Id
AND CandidateSerials.City = EmployerSerials.City
WHERE EmployerSerials.MobileNo ='000000000'
```

Comment: Thanks DanFromGermany

Comment: you're welcome, pleased to hear that it worked for you